# Ruby on Rails - Saving user input troubles

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have been trying to allow the user to input a name for an activity and then save it into the database. However, I am running into the the multiple issues

The first of which is the following:

> ActionController::ParameterMissing in ActivitiesController#create

and the line it refers to is the following:

> params.require(:activities).permit(:a_name)

I have looked some solutions to this and from what I understand, it stems from the "require(:activities)" part of that line. What I don't understand is why having that particular line results in the error.

Removing the ".remove(:activities)" will fix it but I run into another issue where when I input a name and then click the "Create" button, it thinks that I did not have a name and throws a validation error.

> Validation failed: A name can't be blank, A name is too short (minimum
>   is 1 character)

and the line it refers to:

> if @activities.save!

This leads me to believe that my code for the "form_for" is incorrect and is not treating what is in the text field as an input for the name. I'm still very new to HTML and Ruby on Rails so could anyone see what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Activities Model:

```
class Activity < ApplicationRecord

  validates :a_name, presence: true, length: {minimum: 1}    
end
```

Activities Controller:

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
  def display
    @activities = Activity.all
  end

  def index
    @activities = Activity.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @activities = Activity.new
  end

  def create
    @activities = Activity.create(activities_params)
    if @activities.save!
      flash[:success] = 'Activity created successfully!'
      redirect_to activities_display_path
    else
      flash[:error] = 'ERROR: Activity was not saved!'
      #render_to_string #normally would have it render to the name of view ex: :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @activities = Activity.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @activities = Activity.update(activities_params)
    if @activities.save!
      flash[:success] = 'Activity successfully updated!'
      redirect_to root
    else
      flash[:error] = 'ERROR: Activity failed to update'
      render_to_string
    end
  end

  private
    def activities_params
       params.require(:activities).permit(:a_name)
    end

end
```

Activities New HTML:

```
<body>
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
<% end %>

<%= form_for @activities  do |a| %>
    <div class = "form-group">
      <div class = "row top-buffer text-center">
        <div class='col-md-3'>
          <%= a.label :a_name, 'Activity Name' %>:
          <%= a.text_field :a_name %>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class ="row top-buffer text-center">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <%= a.submit 'Create', class: 'btn btn-primary'%>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<% end %>

</body>
```

Comment: Can you check what parameters your form is actually passing? You can use the browser's dev tools or the Rails log for the request. I suspect the parameter is `activity[a_name]`, not `activities[a_name]`. In that case, you'd need to change the params method to use `require(:activity)`.

Comment: @Max You are right. The parameters that my form is passing was "activity[a_name]" and not "activities[a_name]" as I thought. Thank you so much for the fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Max commented, my mistake was thinking the parameter was "activities[a_name]" and not "activity[a_name]".

Changing

```
params.require(:activities).permit(:a_name)
```

to

```
params.require(:activity).permit(:a_name)
```

fixed the first error and subsequently allowed me to save user inputs. Thanks for the help Max